# What is the way to update data saved in database with using ORM like Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I've one questions to my program. I'm writing a console application in C# with using entity framework. This program has two table in one-to-many relationship. The first table is called "Car" and the second is "DescriptionCar". I assume that I've data in the database and I want to add a description to a specific car using its ID.

At the moment I have something like that:

```
using (var context = new ContextClass())
{
    Car car = context.Cars.Single(a => a.CarId == id);
    DescriptionCar descriptionCar = new DescriptionCar();
}
```

At the beginning, I download the data of a specific car, create a new object to add a description and now I do not know how to fill in the data.

**Model classes:**

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Fuel { get; set; }
    public int ProductionYear { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int PowerEngine { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DescriptionCar> DescriptionCars { get; set; }
}

public class DescriptionCar
{
    public int DescriptionCarId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show us the two models of the `Car` and `DescriptionCar`. I assume you want to do something like `descriptionCar.Foo = "something"; descriptionCar.Bar = "somethingElse"; car.Description = descriptionCar;`?

Comment: I have several methods to add data to the database, delete etc. And in addition I also have a method in which I want to add a new description or add to an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're hung up on the EF portion of this or working with an ICollection.  This should work:

```
//Your existing code
Car car = context.Cars.Single(a => a.CarId == id);
DescriptionCar descriptionCar = new DescriptionCar();

//Code to save a new description to your ICollection
List<DescriptionCar> descriptions = new List<DescriptionCar>(); //List to work with

if (car.DescriptionCars!= null) 
{
  descriptions = (List<DescriptionCar>)car.DescriptionCars; //Load existing ICollection into our List
}

descriptions.Add(descriptionCar); //Add the new description
car.DescriptionCars = descriptions; //Store the working list into the EF object
context.Save(); //Save to the database
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways you can accomplish this. The easiest would be the following:

```
using (var context = new ContextClass())
{
    DescriptionCar descriptionCar = context.DescriptionCars.Single(a => a.CarId == id);
    descriptionCar.Description = "Your description";
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can assist you further if you share your entity classes.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things are the most difficult. I will continue to work alone, if I have any problems, I will write.Thanks for your answer.